# no itemdatabound/rowdatabound for datagrid in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I googled and understood there is no itemdatabound or rowdatabound in winforms. I need to use RowAdded and or CellFormatting...

Datagridview - Winforms - C#

I have the 2 following situation and I don't know how to fix.
My datasource is a Genericlist.... List
The "Document" list contains DocumentNumber, DocType, AccountNumber and Amount.
e.g.

```
 DocumentNumber = 100         type-> int
 DocType        = F           type-> string
 AccountNumber  = 9873        type-> String
 Amount         = 12345.25    type-> Decimal
```

My datagrid should look like

```
DocumentNumber  Dotype      AccountNumber    AccountDescription    Amount  
100              F             9873            VAT return           12.345,25
101              C             4341            VAT payable         - 3.326,63
```

requirement:

1) Retrieve for every row the AccountDescription and put on the Grid. So when for every row get the accountnumber and call a function which retrieves the Accountdescription and put on the Datagrid column.

2) When the Doctype = "C" and make the amount field negative (in other words put a minus front of of the amount)

3) Apply a formatting to the amount input: 12345.25 and make it 12.345,25

```
 //make the Credit amount negative
    void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "TypeDoc" && e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "C")
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            //make the amount fields negative and apply formatting.
            row.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Value,  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-be")) * -1;
        }
    }
```

***PROBLEM:***

1) How to retrieve the AccountDescription, CellFormatting is looping over every Cell? I mean in which EVENT do I need to call a function and passing the AcountNumber so it returns the Description and put the description in Datagrid column back????

2) I'm using the Cellformatting to Check whether the doctype is C and if it's "C" apply color RED and make it negative and apply formatting....
But the issues is the red works fine... not the Negative... When I click on the row (which is red) it shows the Negative sign in amount. When I click on other row the negative sign (minus) comes back and when I click on another and back again the red it shows the negative sign...

I also tried using rowsAdded event but after 2-3 loops it finishes and even it loops sometimes 2-3  don't know why.....

So in short: If I want to loop over every row in datagridView (after bind) to change the value what do I need to do?

So what's the thing behind the Cellformatting. how to achieve the 2 steps above?

Comment: if your using a generic list, then can't you update the values in the list before putting them in the grid?

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I need to process the generic list later in databindcompleted... putting total values etc. so I need to keep the original list.